# Really strange Net::SMTP error for certain email

Tags: ruby, email, smtp

Why this email adress `desp@mariacamorales.com` is generating an exception.

```
 `check_response': 550 5.1.1 <desp@mariacamorales.com>... User unknown (Net::SMTPFatalError)
```

The original script is

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'mail'
require 'active_support/time'
today = Date.today
year, month, day = today.to_s.split("-")

subject = "Backup base de datos #{ today }"

to = ["desp@mariacamorales.com"]

mail = Mail.new(subject: subject, body: subject, from: "backup@mydomain.com", to: to)
mail.add_file "/home/project/backups/data/#{ year }/#{ month }/#{ today }-sada.bz2"
mail.deliver!
```

The script works fine with other emails adresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `550` error is a response from the SMTP server you are connecting to.  The server must have the `mariacamorales.com` domain configured as local and the user `desp` does not exist there.

`mail` defaults to sending via localhost so you will probably have a `qmail`, `postfix`, `sendmail` or `exim` process dealing with SMTP. These would normally default to the hosting email the suffix of the hostname of the machine (<del>`host.`</del>`domain.com`). Each can have domains configured independently of the hostname of the machine.

If you are not sure where to start, `sudo grep -ir mariacamorales.com /etc` might point to what you need.

Comment: I have looked at /etc/hosts as well as all /ect/host* and none is there, also looked at apache sites-enabled and NO.

Comment: It's unlikely Apache httpd will be involved in SMTP. I've added some mail server notes to the A.